# After element to only apply to span

Tags: css

I have a section of code like this..

```css
.hero_title .yellow-under::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  bottom: 100%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: #FFD400;
  transform: translateY(250%);
}
```

```html
<div class="hero_title">
  <h1>
    <span class="yellow-under">HOW TO:</span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

It's supposed to just "underline" the words "How To:", but the line goes all the way across the entire `div`. Is there a way to just restrict it to the span?

Comment: make the span relative and the absolute child will use it for coordonates reference

Comment: @G-Cyr Are you saying change to `position: relative`?

Comment: no, the span , the pseudo is absolute and is a virtual child of span;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demo from my comment ;)

> make the span relative and the absolute child will use it for coordonates reference

```css
.hero_title .yellow-under::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  bottom: 100%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: #FFD400;
  transform: translateY(250%);
}

.yellow-under {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero_title">
  <h1>
    <span class="yellow-under">HOW TO:</span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

**inset shadow can do the visual from a single CSS line**

```css
.hero_title span {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -16px #FFD400;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero_title">
  <h1>
    <span class="yellow-under">HOW TO:</span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

**same thing with gradient**

```css
.hero_title span {
  background:linear-gradient(#FFD400,#FFD400) bottom/100% 16px no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero_title">
  <h1>
    <span class="yellow-under">HOW TO:</span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I guess I need to read up on how `after` works!

Comment: @jonmrich You should consider looking at Pilan's answer aswell, in case you don't actually need to be using 'after', their first solution is much cleaner.

Comment: @jonmrich Look at position relative/absolute to find out when to use them. Else as commented in the other answer, you can also play with line-height and border. You could also use an inset shadow or gradient.

Comment: so let's add the gradient then :p

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be ::after?

```css
.hero_title .yellow-under {
  border-bottom: 16px solid #FFD400;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero_title">
  <h1>
    <span class="yellow-under">HOW TO:</span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

If not, use this.

```css
.hero_title .yellow-under {
  position: relative;
}

.hero_title .yellow-under::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  bottom: 0%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: #FFD400;
  transform: translateY(16px);
}
```

```html
<div class="hero_title">
  <h1>
    <span class="yellow-under">HOW TO:</span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: You used my comment/answer ;) (about relative) . for the border, it can work if you reset display and line-height for the span: update from your original answer : `.hero_title .yellow-under {
  border-bottom: 16px solid #FFD400;
  line-height:0.2em;
  display:inline-block;
}`